# AWS EC2 Running 2 server Apache & NGINX on diffrent instances

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hy guys,

may i ask,

i am kinda new with AWS things,

How to run 2 instances at the same time,

with both have diffrent server like Apache and NGINX,

is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Each instance is completely independent, you can run whatever operating system and software you like on each server.

You can run Apache and Nginx on the same instance, so long as they attach to different ports.